# Whether we have $|\nabla^m \mathring A| \le C(m,n) |\nabla^m A|$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, mean-curvature-flows

Consider a hypersurface $M^n\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$, $A$ is the second fundamental form, $\mathring A= A-\frac{H}{n}g$  where $H$ is mean curvature and $g$ is induced metric. From  [**Blow-up of the mean curvature at the first singular time of the mean curvature flow**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00526-016-1003-x), it seems that they used
$$
|\nabla^2 \mathring A| \le C(n)|\nabla^2 A|.
$$
In fact, I don't know how to prove it. Besides, Whether we have 
$$
|\nabla^m \mathring A| \le C(m,n) |\nabla^m A| ~~?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$ \nabla^m \mathring A = \nabla^m A - \frac{1}{n} \nabla^m H\otimes g$$
since $\nabla g = 0$. Thus

$$\begin{split}
|\nabla^m \mathring A| &\le |\nabla^m A| + \frac{1}{n} |\nabla^m H \otimes g|\\
&= |\nabla^m A| + \frac{1}{n} |\nabla ^m H| \cdot |g|\\
&=|\nabla^m A|+\frac{1}{\sqrt n} |\nabla ^m H|.
\end{split}$$

Note $H = g^{ij} A_{ij} = \mathrm{tr}(g^{-1} \otimes A)$. Thus

$$\nabla^m H= \mathrm{tr} (g^{-1} \otimes \nabla^m A).$$

If we calculate at a point where $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$, then by Cauchy Schwarz,

$$\begin{split}
|\nabla^m H|^2 &= \sum_{j_1, \cdots, j_m} \left(\sum_i \nabla^m_{j_1\cdots j_m} A_{ii}\right)^2 \\
&\le n\sum_{j_1, \cdots, j_m} \left(\sum_i (\nabla^m_{j_1\cdots j_m} A_{ii})^2\right)\\
&\le n\sum_{i,j, j_1, \cdots, j_m} \left( \nabla^m_{j_1\cdots j_m} A_{ij}\right)^2 \\
&= n|\nabla^m A|^2.
\end{split}$$

So we have

$$|\nabla^m \mathring A| \le 2|\nabla ^m A|$$

and the constant $C(n,m)=2$ does not depend on $m,n$.

Comment: Very good, I always fail to do likeling calculation.

Comment: Although $\nabla g=0$ in normal frame,  $\Delta g = 0 $ ?

Comment: $\nabla g$ as a three tensor is identically zero. This is true for whatever frame you use. Simiilar for $\Delta g$, which is just $\mathrm{tr} \nabla^2 g$.@lanse7pty